# What is the name of the peak in Meghalya, India?

Tags: india, identify-this, mountains

[image]

What is the name of the peak? It's in Meghalya, India. It's most probably in garo hills or khasi hills district.

Answer (score 3):

[This link](https://smilingbangladesh.com/pin/652) shows what looks to be the same peak:

[image]

Birishiri of Shusong Durgapur, Netrokona

The exact image you show is also named as Birishiri on this [blog](http://blog.tour.com.bd/%E0%A6%AC%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%B6%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%BF-%E0%A6%A6%E0%A7%81%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%97%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%AA%E0%A7%81%E0%A6%B0/) and Durgapur Upazila, Bangladesh on [Panoramio](http://www.panoramio.com/photo/75279591) saying:

> This picture is taken from Birisiri, Shusong-Durgapur. Photographer is
>   unknown, do not be confuse because I found this picture from friend of
>   mine, But this is the place where i grew up and this is my country
>   side. That beautiful blue mountain you are seeing in the picture is
>   called **Garo Pahar** which is really located in India.